# Can we get the items in combo to be displayed in a checkbox in Java SWT?

Tags: java, checkbox, combobox, dropdown, swt

How can we generate list of items in checkbox dynamically when we select an item1 in dropdown -- JAVA SWT?

```
item1 - A , B, C in drop down 
list1 when A is selected -- AA, AB, AC
list2 when B is selected ---  BA, BB, BC, BD
list3 when C is selected --- CA, CB, CC, CD
```

Lists should be in checkbox
I tried Combo.
works when tried to display the list in dropdown but not for checkbox

```java
Label item = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("Item");

comboitem = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY); 
comboitem.setItems(sysConfig.items); 
comboitem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {             
   @Override
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {  
      combolist.setItems(sysConfig.getModuleByCategory(cmbCategory.getText())); 
});

Label list = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE); 
combolist = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: don't add details to the question in a comment, instead edit the question (as gregg did for you Here)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSelectionIndex` to get the selection index in the first Combo.

Something like:

```
Label item = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("Item");

Combo comboitem = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboitem.setItems("A", "B", "C");

Label list = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
list.setText("List");
Combo combolist = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY);

comboitem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {

    switch (comboitem.getSelectionIndex())
    {
      case 0 -> combolist.setItems("AA", "AB", "AC");
      case 1 -> combolist.setItems("BA", "BB", "BC", "BD");
      case 2 -> combolist.setItems("CA", "CB", "CC", "CD");
    }

    combolist.select(0);
  }});
```

Note that you also need to call `select(0)` to make the first item of the list visible in the combo.

I have used the enhanced `switch` syntax here which needs a modern version of Java - it will need small changes for older versions of Java.

Alternatively this uses a checkbox Table and resets the items:

```
final Combo comboitem = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboitem.setItems("A", "B", "C");

final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER);

// Assumes parent Composite is using GridLayout. Adjust as required
final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false);
data.heightHint = 100;
data.widthHint = 100;
table.setLayoutData(data);

comboitem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {

    switch (comboitem.getSelectionIndex())
    {
      case 0 -> createItems(table, "AA", "AB", "AC");
      case 1 -> createItems(table, "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD");
      case 2 -> createItems(table, "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD");
    }
 }});
```

```
  private static void createItems(final Table table, final String... items)
  {
    table.removeAll();

    for (final String item : items) {
      final TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
      tableItem.setText(item);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will display the lists in dropdown right? I want them to be displayed with checkboxes

Comment: Combo does not support check boxes. You would have to use a Table with SWT.CHECK and that doesn't support drop-down

Comment: I have revised the Table example to update the contents

Comment: How can we retrieve the selected/checked items ?

Comment: `TableItem.getChecked` to see if an item is checked. `Table.getItems` to get all the items.